# Calculating $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2n} x \ dx $, please check my work.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

In order to calculate the integral $$I \equiv \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2n} x  \ dx, $$ I first express it in the form $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) ie^{it}dt = \oint_{|z|=1}f(z)dz.$$

By substituting for the cosine, I get:

$$I = -\frac{i}{4^n}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{(z^2-1)^{2n}}{z^{2n+1}}dz$$

This guy has a pole of order $2n+1$ at $z=0$. So to find the residue, I attempt to expand in a Laurent series, letting:

$$f(z)\equiv (1+(-z^2))^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}(-1)^k z^{2k} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{2n} a_k z^k $$
$$g(z) \equiv z^{2n+1}$$
$$h(z) \equiv \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \sum_{k=-(2n+1)}^{\infty}c_k z^k$$

We're after the residue, $c_{-1}$. Then,

$$g(z)h(z)=z^{2n+1}(c_{-(2n+1)} z^{2n+1}+\cdots+\frac{c_{-1}}{z}+\cdots) = c_{-(2n+1)}+\cdots+c_{-1}z^{2n}+\cdots$$
$$=f(z)$$

Comparing coefficients, we get that

$$c_{-1}=a_{2n}={2n\choose n}.$$

Therefore, $$I=-\frac{i}{4^n} \ 2\pi i {2n\choose n}=\frac{2\pi}{4^n}{2n\choose n}.$$

Is my solution correct? Or just correct up to an additive constant?

Comment: Clearly, at least the $(-1)^n$ shouldn't be there as the integrand is positive.

Comment: Of course, corrected now!

Comment: You can check it yourself by computing the integral using ordinary integration. $\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos 2x)$. In terms of the beta function the answer is $2  \beta(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2n+1}{2})$.

Comment: Must you use contour integration? Reduction formulae are typically very good at solving this type of problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll check using a simple complex approach: 
$$
\begin{split}
\cos^{2n}x &= \left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}e^{ikx}e^{-i(2n-k)x} \\ &= \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}e^{i(2k-2n)x} \end{split}
$$
The terms with $k\ne n$ integrate to zero over $[0,2\pi]$, and we are left with
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}x \,dx = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n} \,dx = \frac{2\pi}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}
$$
Same answer. (Indeed, some of the computational steps overlap with yours, though expressed differently.)